# Burninating [mod]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I think the [mod](/questions/tagged/mod)-tag should be burinated. It seems to be used in the following situations:

- Where an apache mod is referenced, for example [mod-rewrite](/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) or [mod-auth](/questions/tagged/mod-auth). They should be tagged with that specific mod, [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) or [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) depending on the context
- In the context of mathematical calculations, it is often used for the [modulo](/questions/tagged/modulo) operator (`5 % 2 = 1`)
- In the context of operating systems, games or platforms (forums for example) it is usually used to reference a [module](/questions/tagged/module)

I found one question that was related to [modulation](/questions/tagged/modulation) that was also tagged with [mod](/questions/tagged/mod).

What should be done with [mod]? The two main definitions seem to be module (even in apache context it is a module that is being referenced) and modulo, so I don't think we can make it a synonym of a tag. Retagging all the questions and burning the tag seems the best option to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: In the context of games I'd have said it meant "modification"

Comment: Well, there is (luckily) no tag [tag:modification] (and [tag:modify] may not be used), and for games it is usually used for a "mod" they are writing, which is essentially a module or addition on the game itself

Comment: Some of those modulo questions are actually talking about a function called "`mod`", which is a bit different than it just being an abbreviation haphazardly slapped on a question. Whether every function needs its own tag, of course, is debatable. And the rest of them definitely need to be cleaned up anyway.

Comment: @Wooble What does a `mod` function do if it isn't related to modulo?

Comment: It is related to modulo, but the questions are asking about the behavior of a specific function rather than the concept of modulus. But that doesn't *necessarily* mean they deserve a separate tag, just wanted to bring it up since it's not the same sort of problem as people slapping "mod" onto questions where they mean "modification" or "modulation" or "module"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terrible, horrible, hot, raging fire, the [mod](/questions/tagged/mod)-tag will burn to crisps and ashes tonight, as all questions with this tag are now re-tagged (finally!).